# C# - gui question

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface

Does someone know if there are any libraries or components written in *C# (or C++)* which allow to create **gui** similiar to the one used in the `Adobe` products *(Photoshop, After Effects, etc)*?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to be more specific.  Exactly which part of those products are you trying to duplicate?

Comment: @Chris Basically, I'm not trying to duplicate their products, I just like the overall gui approach used by Adobe - toolbars, sidebars and their dark-gray style.

Comment: @Chris And, well, I guess something similiar can be implemented manually, but I simply wanted to ask - maybe somebody already had an attempt to do this and stored his results as a library.

Comment: Okay, so you're talking about the floating toolbars..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to build slick, [themeable](http://www.google.be/search?q=wpf+themes) GUIs, take a look at [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).

Comment: I vote for WPF myself any day.  That implies you are coding in the .NET world, probably with C#.  But if for some reason you have a constraint to use unmanaged C++ codejock is probably your best bet to accomplish themed UIs.

Comment: If you go with WPF, there is a nice tool called Kaxaml to build and test your themes.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe products are written in CodeWarrior  - a Motorola product. Your not going to get the same look with .Net buttons. My advice is to check out CodeJock or DevComponents and make a custom theme, here you go: http://www.codejock.com/products/skinframework/tour_4.asp?platform=

*Edit I cant find a Adobe msstyle and I'm sure your not the only one who would like an Adobe skin, hence you could probably make some pocket money selling the skin if you make it...

Answer (score 0):

Those are basically non-modal forms with a z order that places them on top.  To achieve the specific look, just adjust your fonts etc.

Of course, the complication is going to come in when syncing the selection in the toolbar with the main form.